# How to create a right bounded tree from a normal tree in C++ (Huffman)?

Tags: c++, sorting, tree, binary-tree, huffman-code

How to build a right bounded Huffman tree (so that the depth of any left child on any node is not larger than the depth on the right child on this node).

I already have a Huffman tree from [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Huffman_coding#C++). The LeafNode's are the one with the symbols on it and no children and the InternalNode's are the one that have children.
My Idea would be to make a normal Huffman tree first and then sort it. To do this (every symbol should have the same amount of bits afterwards) I would go through the created Huffman tree and sort every Node in one row by their (largest) depth.

Does anyone have a good Idea how to program this in C++ or an easier solution to build a right bounded Huffman tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to build a right-bounded Huffman tree is to modify the standard Huffman tree building algorithm. Here's one way to do it in C++:

```
void buildRightBoundedTree(Node* root) {
if (root == nullptr) return;

// Compare the depth of the left and right children
if (root->left->depth > root->right->depth) {
    // Swap the children
    Node* temp = root->left;
    root->left = root->right;
    root->right = temp;
}

// Recursively apply the procedure to the children
buildRightBoundedTree(root->left);
buildRightBoundedTree(root->right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just build the tree that way in the first place. Add a `const int d;` to `INode`, and construct with `INode(int f, int d) : f(f), d(d) {}`. Construct `Leaf` with `LeafNode(int f, char c) : INode(f, 0), c(c) {}`. Construct `InternalNode` with:

```
InternalNode(INode* c0, INode* c1) :
    INode(c0->f + c1->f, std::max(c0->d, c1->d) + 1),
          left(c0->d > c1->d ? c1 : c0), right(c0->d > c1->d ? c0 : c1) {}
```

By the way, there is bug in the Rosetta Code. It should be:

```
++frequencies[*(unsigned char *)ptr++];
```

Otherwise bytes above 127 result in a negative index.